# html5 elements do not display correctly in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, html

My site works fine in Chrome and Safari but elements do not display correctly in firefox or ie. Some elements get shoved right and I don't understand how to solve the problem.

You can see the site [here](http://www.blackstonecreativegroup.com)

I've added outlines to the CSS to help diagnose what elements aren't working:

```
> #leftwrap {float: left; width: 270px; outline: 1px dashed green;}

> #slider-frame {height: 505px; margin: 20px 20px 0 302px; overflow: hidden; outline: 1px dashed blue;}
```

Or is it the old version of JQuery that's linked? When I tried to update to the latest version of JQuery everything blew apart in all browsers.

The site seemed to be working fine until recently when someone gave me a heads up. I hired a developer for this site a few years ago and now he's no longer available. So any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have some positioning issues. Just remove floats from everywhere, starting by

```
#leftwrap{float:left}
```

then give your #poster div

```
#poster {position: relative;}
```

your `#leftwrap` something like

```
#leftwrap {
    width: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

`.slide-width` is correct, just remove the inline style, add it to CSS and add the height as well

then #main-slide-nav something like this:

```
#main-slide-nav {
    margin-left: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 650px;
}
```

Of course these are approximations, you'll need to adjust to your specific taste and then fine tune, but this way you'll have your layout working in all browsers

Comment: Thanks Fabio... but I'm not sure what you mean by: .slide-width is correct, just remove the inline style, add it to CSS and add the height as well

Comment: you have an inline style in your markup, just get used to declare CSS styles in your style sheet so it's easy to manage

Comment: Thanks Fabio... OK maybe I am clueless... I searched index.html and portfolio.html and could not find an instance of .slide-with defined as an inline style...

Comment: I can't see it now, so probably a mistake of mine

Comment: OK... I adjusted the CSS as you suggested... elements are now positioned correctly in all browsers (I will need to tweak later) ...but now the images do not appear when you click on the numbered buttons at the bottom... and I don't know what changed...

Comment: Update ...but now the images do not appear when you click on the numbered buttons at the bottom in Firefox... works OK in Safari and Chrome...